# The property is not a navigation property of entity type

Tags: linq, ef-core-2.0

I've designed my entities attached in the below diagram.
[image]

For this schema I would have written following query in sql to get all the roles, activities, applications for this user in the following way

```
select * from users u, roles r, userroles ur, roleappactivities raa, applications ap, activities ac
where u.Id = ur.UserId
and ur.RoleId = r.Id
and r.Id = raa.RoleId
and raa.ApplicationId = ap.Id
and raa.ActivityId = ac.Id
and u.id = 1
```

For the same to be achieved in my core application, I've written following code, which is failing. I ran out of ideas of how to achieve the above query through the following code. Any help much appreciated.

```
_context.Users
                .Include("Roles")
                .Include("RoleAppActivities")
                .Include("Applications")
                .Include("Activities")
                .Where(x => x.Id == id)
                .Select(x => new User
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    TId = x.TId,
                    Roles = x.Roles

                })
```

Edit:

Here are my entities

```
 public class User
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }        
        public ICollection<UserRole> Roles { get; set; }
    }
```

public class UserRole
    {

```
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User{ get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public Role Role{get; set;}
}
 public class Role
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserRole> Users { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RoleApplicationActivity> RoleApplicationActivity { get; set; }
    }

 public class RoleApplicationActivity
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public int ActivityId { get; set; }

        public Activity Activity { get; set; }
        public Application Application { get; set; }
        public Role Role { get; set; }
    }

public class Activity
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RoleApplicationActivity> RoleApplicationActivity { get; set; }
    }


 public class Application
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RoleApplicationActivity> RoleApplicationActivity { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: It seems that you didn't configure the navigation properties for User entity. Would you share the entities ?

Comment: It's is well-documented how to do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've to modify my query to following to fix the issue.

```
from u in _context.Users
                   from r in _context.Roles
                   from app in _context.Applications
                   from ac in _context.Activities
                   where u.Id == 1
                   select u
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your entity User should have the others collections (Roles , 
 RoleAppActivities..). So you can directly load them by using .include(user=> user.Collection) , i think it is more strongly typed than using the .include("string)"..